# If f(x) is continuous, can it be uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

The question states: Assume that $f(x)$ is continuous on $(0,3)$. Each of these statements are either true or false.

I am having trouble proving that $f$  is uniformly continuous on $(0,3)$ and that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(1,2)$.  I know what it means to be uniform continuous on a closed interval and what not, but I am having trouble on getting Theorems to show that they are uniformly continuous.

Please use some basic theorems about continuous and uniform continuity and bounds on the interval if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $f$ is continuous on the interval $(0,3)$ then it's continuous on the compact $[1,2]$ so by the [Heine-Cantor theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity) $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[1,2]$.

Comment: does that mean it is true for the open interval (1,2)? Because we have not learned about Heine-Cantors Theorem yet.

Comment: No the function $x\mapsto \frac 1x$ is continuous on $(0,1)$ but not uniformly continuous on this interval.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane under the assumptions given, $f$ is necessarily uniformly continuous on $(1, 2)$, because it's uniformly continuous on $[1, 2]$.

Comment: Not sure you can prove this without having to go through Heine-Cantor or Heine-Borel -- the fact that every continuous function on a closed interval is uniformly continuous on this interval is not trivial.

Answer (score 1):

- $f$ need not be uniformly continuous on $(0,3)$. Take for instance $x\mapsto \frac1x$.
- if it is continuous on $(0,3)$, $f$ is in particular continuous on $[1,2]$. So apply Heine-Cantor theorem to get that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[1,2]$, hence on $(1,2)$.